# How to refer obfuscated public fields from other .dlls

Tags: .net

I obfuscated all the public and private fields in some dlls, but problem is, when I use these dlls in my project, other dll not able to refer obfuscated fields in obfuscated dll. Is there any way to access obfuscated fields. Please help me...
(I obfuscated dll using DotFuscator tool.)

Thank you

Comment: Your obfuscator should have a setting for _not_ obfuscating public members...

Comment: Yes obfuscator has setting to not obfuscate bublic members but my requirment is to obfuscate all the members, whether it is public or private.